# Deleting multiple admin accounts in Batch ( Win7 )

Tags: batch-file, account

I have big problem trying to delete all Administrator accounts (beside 2 specyfic) using net localgroups. The problem is that there is no AND operator, so it must be done is some harder way.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('net localgroup administrators') Do (
If %%G == Administrator (goto:ex)
If %%G == MWAdmin (goto:ex)
net localgroup administrators %%G /delete
:ex)
```

Comment: This code is working, but is deleting every admin account but Administrator, even MWAdmin...

Comment: Also, welcome to stack overflow, thanks for showing your attempt and not dwelling into verbose detail. In the future you can edit your post to add the error, rather than leaving it as a comment. Remember to mark what solves your answer with the check mark by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the line:

```
:ex)
```

This makes no sense to batch, labels cannot be in a code block, as it breaks the block and batch gives up due to a syntax error.

You can solve this by checking the account name outside of the block with `call`; as `goto :eof` used after `call` goes back to the `call`, thus allowing for leaving and returning to where it left off in a for loop.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('net localgroup administrators') do (
    call :checkName "%%~G"
)

:: If name matches if, go back to for loop, else del.
:checkName
if "%~1" == "Administrator" goto :eof
if "%~1" == "MWAdmin" goto :eof     
net localgroup administrators "%~1" /delete
goto :eof
```

Just in case, lets highlight:

```
call :label "%variable%"
```

Using this means that when it goes to `:label`, you can use `%1` to get `%variable%`'s value on pass, and `~` can be added with `%~1` to remove quotes. This is mainly useful to take the value of `%%X` outside of a for loop for easier processing.

---

Or use a `neq` and nested `neq` method in a for loop;

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('net localgroup administrators') do (
    if "%%~G" neq "Administrator" (
        if "%%~G" neq "MWAdmin" (
            net localgroup administrators %%G /delete
        )
    )
)
```

Note i made `%%G` into `%%~G`, and added quotes around `Administrator` and `MWAdmin`, this is for stability, in-case a future name causes syntax errors.